# search api gives wrong result when element do not have valid value present

Tags: marklogic

I am using range index in search api. I get wrong result when my document has blank or invalid entry for an element used in range index. Below is the sample code. Please let me know how can I exclude this blank/invalid values while performing search to get proper result.

```
{cts:and-query((cts:directory-query((' + searchDir + ')),cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("document-status"), "active"),cts:element-query(xs:QName("version"),cts:and-query((cts:element-attribute-value-query(fn:QName("","version"), fn:QName("","version-status"), "active", ("lang=en"), 1),cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("","expiration-date"), ">=", xs:date("' +expDtStart + '"), (), 1),cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("","expiration-date"), "<=", xs:date("' +expDtEnd + '"), (), 1)))) ))}
```

expiration-date is my element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid values are hard to exclude, but empty elements can be excluded with a:

```
cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('expiration-date'), ""))
```

It might be easier though to toggle the `invalid-values` setting of the range index to `reject` rather than `ignore`.

HTH!

Comment: I did the suggested change but now result is always 0. Adding complete query(in another comment) with the suggested changes. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: {cts:and-query((cts:directory-query((' + searchDir + ')),cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("document"), xs:QName("document-status"),"active"),cts:element-query(xs:QName("version"),cts:and-query((cts:element-attribute-value-query(fn:QName("","version"), fn:QName("","version-status"), "active",("lang=en"), 1),cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName("expiration-date"), cts:true-query())), cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("","expiration-date"), ">=", xs:date("' +expDtStart + '"),(), 1),cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("","expiration-date"), "<=", xs:date("' +expDtEnd + '"), (), 1)))) ))}

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. you have to use a not on element-value-query for empty string.. I'll update the answer..